# Dates in Excel to convert to a Julian date

Tags: excel, vba

So, I'm trying to convert a column of dates from mm/dd/yyyy in excel to Julian format (just a number between 1 and 365/366) and the code I have posted below won't work.
I then tried making it as a function only to be met with "Compile Error: Expected:End of statement. Any help would be appreciated.

```
=TEXT(A2,"yy")&TEXT((A2-DATEVALUE("1/1/"&TEXT(A2,"yy"))+1),"000")
```

The intention is to make this reproducible over multiple spreadsheets for a long period of time which is why I tried coding it as a function.

edit for clarity:

```
Function Julian Transform=TEXT(A2,"yy")&TEXT((A2-DATEVALUE("1/1/"&TEXT(A2,"yy"))+1),"000") End Function
```

Comment: It works for me,  If I put `4/6/2018` in A2, I get `18096`

Comment: Are your dates true dates and not text that look like dates?

Comment: Also you should post the code that get the compile error.

Comment: Sorry, How can I figure out if they're true dates or text that looks like dates?
Function Julian Transform=TEXT(A2,"yy")&TEXT((A2-DATEVALUE("1/1/"&TEXT(A2,"yy"))+1),"000")
End Function

Comment: please [edit] the post to put the code in, code cannot be formatted properly in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
=A2-DATE(YEAR(A2),1,0)
```

to get the *day of the year*. This isn't the Julian date by the way. That's something different. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day